# Split large dataframe into small ones Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DF that has 200 million lines. I cant group this DF and I have to split this DF in 8 smaller DFs (approx 30 million lines each). I've tried this [approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyspark-split-dataframe-into-equal-number-of-rows/) but with no success. Without caching the DF, the count of the splitted DFs does not match the larger DF. If I use cache I get out of disk space (my config is 64gb RAM and 512 SSD).

Considering this, I though about the following approach:

1. Load the entire DF
2. Give 8 random numbers to this DF
3. Distribute the random number evenly in the DF

Consider the following DF as example:

```
+------+--------+
| val1 |  val2  |
+------+--------+
|Paul  |    1.5 |
|Bostap|    1   |
|Anna  |    3   |
|Louis |    4   |
|Jack  |    2.5 |
|Rick  |    0   |
|Grimes|    null|
|Harv  |    2   |
|Johnny|    2   |
|John  |    1   |
|Neo   |    5   |
|Billy |    null|
|James |    2.5 |
|Euler |    null|
+------+--------+
```

The DF has 14 lines, I though to use window to create the following DF:

```
+------+--------+----+
| val1 |  val2  | sep|
+------+--------+----+
|Paul  |    1.5 |1   |
|Bostap|    1   |1   |
|Anna  |    3   |1   |
|Louis |    4   |1   |
|Jack  |    2.5 |1   |
|Rick  |    0   |1   |
|Grimes|    null|1   |
|Harv  |    2   |2   |
|Johnny|    2   |2   |
|John  |    1   |2   |
|Neo   |    5   |2   |
|Billy |    null|2   |
|James |    2.5 |2   |
|Euler |    null|2   |
+------+--------+----+
```

Considering the last DF, I will use a filter to filter by sep. My doubt is: **How can I use window function to generate the column sep of last DF?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are randomly splitting the dataframe into 8 parts, you could use [randomSplit()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit.html):

```py
split_weights = [1.0] * 8
splits = df.randomSplit(split_weights)
for df_split in splits:
    # do what you want with the smaller df_split
```

Note that this will not ensure same number of records in each `df_split`. There may be some fluctuation but with 200 million records it will be negligible.

Comment: watchout with the duplicates !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process and store to files with the count names to avoid getting mixed up.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet('parquet-files')
split_w = [1.0] * 5
splits = df.randomSplit(split_w)
for count, df_split in enumerate(splits, start=1):
    df_split.write.parquet(f'split-files/split-file-{count}', mode='overwrite')
```

The file sizes will be averagely the same size, some with a slight difference.